# Union based on Case

Tags: sql-server-2012, case, union

Is there a way to do a Union based on a Case statement something like this:

```
Case
    When @var = 1 Then Select * from TableA Union Select * From TableB
    When @Var = 2 Then Select * From TableC Union Select * From TableD
    When @Var = 3 Then Select * From TableA Union Select * From TableE
    ...
End
```

the exact info and what tables to grab from I can handle I am just curious if this concept is doable on SQL Server 2012.

So based on that comment would this be the proper syntax:

```
IF @var = 1
    Select * from TableA Union Select * From TableB
ELSE
IF @Var = 2
    Select * From TableC Union Select * From TableD
Else
IF @Var = 3
    Select * From TableA Union Select * From TableE
Else
...
```

Comment: you can do this using `IF`

Comment: @Lamak could you please check my syntax on the edit. I had not seen IF used in SQL prior to today. I have missed it since I came from an Excel background. However I do love case.

Comment: @ChadPortman Your syntax is correct.

Comment: Thank you sir. I was able to get it work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on that comment From @Lamak I was able to get my desired result using:

```
IF @var = 1
    Select * from TableA Union Select * From TableB
ELSE
IF @Var = 2
    Select * From TableC Union Select * From TableD
Else
IF @Var = 3
    Select * From TableA Union Select * From TableE
Else
...
```